# Import course information from one Moodle to another

Tags: moodle

I am upgrading the Moodle installation and changing look and feel, roles, etc. To do this i am imposing a content freeze on the existing version, copying the site to a new location, updating it, (we are making a lot of changes), then when ready moving the 'new' site to the old site location.

The problem is we have a number of people part way through a course and do not want to stop them completing but would like a way of taking the partial data relating to their courses intro the new version.

Any ideas? Anyone done this? To dangerous?

Comment: Unless I misundersatnd, this is not programming ready.  You're talking about using Moodle, not extending/programming it, right? Try superuser.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try the built in backup/restore course functionality. i would perform an in-depth test of it before you start the migrations, as at least on old moodle versions (iirc ~1.5 or 1.6), the results of backup / restore were not always perfect..

Answer (score 0):

Your plan sounds reasonable.  Why not after updating the new site, new look, courses, role changes etc, just switching the DNS from the old site to the new?

You could also back up the moodle DB on the old site, I use phpMyAdmin, make the changes in place and then do a in-place upgrade.

Comment: Thanks and you are testing my memory as this was 3.5 years ago. However the client, a major international charity, had built the whole site on a windows pc running it on MAMP with no security and arcane methods of connecting to the outside world, so i was pretty well stuck with making a cludge. However it worked without to many hitches.

Comment: Sounds good.  I have dealt with similar situations over the years on my end and have found moodle to be a pretty upgradable entity.

Comment: I have not used it for a while, last version i used was 1.8. I understand it has changed since 2.0 quite a bit.

Comment: yes, more of a focus on items added to a more narrow context, like an activity of some kind.  New activity types, like a book, more integration with other repositories.  Things that make moodle more feasible on the larger scale.  Internally, the file management, file association/structure has changed a lot.  Moodle 2.5 even comes bundled now with Apache, MySQL and PHP (correct versions of each)